# Using ko.PureComputed List as DataSource for Kendo ComboBox

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-datasource, kendo-combobox

I'm attempting to get the list of selectedJobs below to be a dataSource for the kendoComboBox below. However, the values of the list aren't loading and I'm not getting an error and so I'm unsure of what's wrong. Is what I'm trying possible? Can I not use a ko.pureComputed() returned list as a dataSource? Also, the jobid isn't being recognized as a field for dataValueField even though the selectedJobs has this field. Thank you!

```
pageModel.newServiceModel.selectedJobs = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return pageModel.newServiceModel.selectedAccount() ? pageModel.newServiceModel.selectedAccount().jobs : null;
});

var source = new kendo.data.DataSource(pageModel.newServiceModel.selectedJobs);

$("#newServiceJobs").kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select One",
    filter: "contains",
    suggest: true,
    change: pageModel.newServiceModel.JobSelectionChange,
    dataSource: source,
    //dataValueField: jobid,
    dataTextField: name
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to fix up your existing code:

- To access a pureComputed, you need to call it as a function like: `pageModel.newServiceModel.selectedJobs()`. You can pass that directly in as the `dataSource` property.
- The `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` options expect strings (like "jobid" and "name")
- If you want the control to react to your `selectedJobs` computed changing, then you would need to subscribe to changes and update the control like:

```js
pageModel.newServiceModel.selectedJobs.subscribe( function(newData) {
     $("#newServiceJobs").data( "kendoComboBox" ).dataSource.data( newData );
});
```

Here is a snippet that shows your scenario. Click the "Fill Selected Account" button to populate the `selectedAccount` observable.

```js
const viewModel = {
 selectedAccount: ko.observable(),
  clearSelectedAccount() {
   viewModel.selectedAccount( null );
  },
  fillSelectedAccount() {
      viewModel.selectedAccount({
       jobs: [
         { jobid: "1", name: "one" },
         { jobid: "2", name: "two" }
       ]
     });
  }
};

viewModel.selectedJobs = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    const account = viewModel.selectedAccount();
    return account ? account.jobs : [];
});

ko.applyBindings( viewModel );

$("#newServiceJobs").kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select One",
    filter: "contains",
    suggest: true,
    change: null,
    dataSource: viewModel.selectedJobs(),
    dataValueField: "jobid",
    dataTextField: "name"
});

viewModel.selectedJobs.subscribe( newData => {
 $("#newServiceJobs").data( "kendoComboBox" ).dataSource.data( newData );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/css/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/css/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: fillSelectedAccount">Fill Selected Account</button>
<button data-bind="click: clearSelectedAccount">Clear Selected Account</button>

<hr/>

<input id="newServiceJobs" />
```

Another option, if possible, is to look at `knockout-kendo` that will give you some basic bindings to Kendo UI from Knockout like: http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/ComboBox.html. The library handles keeping the control and view model in sync with each other and avoids you manually having to manage the kendo controls via jQuery.